# Custom Radio button selection bug in angular 6 (inside of ngFor)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6, ngfor

**Selecting radio input inside one item in ngFor triggers other radio inputs checked . Created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-synamic-radio-input-bug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) .**

**Html**

```
<div class='section' *ngFor="let item of radioData">
    <div class="radio-selection">
        <input type="radio" attr.name="radio-{{item.Id}}" value="true" attr.id="radio-first-{{item.Id}}" [(ngModel)]='item.IsSelected'>
        <label attr.for="radio-first-{{item.Id}}">Radio-first {{item.Id}}--value={{item.IsSelected}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-selection">
        <input type="radio" attr.name="radio-{{item.Id}}" value="false" attr.id="radio-second-{{item.Id}}" [(ngModel)]='item.IsSelected'>
        <label attr.for="radio-second-{{item.Id}}">Radio-second {{item.Id}}--value={{item.IsSelected}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.section {
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
}
.radio-selection {
    input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
    }
    input[type="radio"] + label {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      &:hover {
        &:before {
          border-color: green;
        }
      }
    }

    input[type="radio"] + label:before {
      content: "";
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #333;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2px;
      border-radius:50%;
    }

    input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
      background:red;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2.5px #fff;
    }
  }
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `name` instead of `attr.name` to set the name of the input elements (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-synamic-radio-input-bug-ie5rhf)):

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-{{item.Id}}" ...>
```

or use the property binding syntax (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-synamic-radio-input-bug-yvzrsh)):

```
<input type="radio" [name]="'radio-'+item.Id" ...>
```

Comment: Yeah it worked , can you add reason for this strange behaviour ?

Comment: If you notice , `name="radio-{{item.Id}}"` or `[name]="'radio-'+item.Id"` will not add name attribute in radio input .

Comment: @Sachin - When checking a radio button, the browser automatically unchecks the other radio buttons with the same name. Angular may prefer to keep the radio buttons unnamed, to do its own handling without having to fight against that automatic handling by the browser.